# xml query help returning multiple nodes

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

I've been working with SQL for a long time but new systems require me to learn XQuery.

I have had a good search but can't really find a newbie answer to this one, I'm trying to query an XML field to return multiple rows of data where a client has multiple telephone numbers. The XML field is stored at the client level and is of the form:

```
   <p1:Telephone>
     <p1:Type code="Home">Home</p1:Type>
     <p1:TelephoneNumber>01234 987654</p1:TelephoneNumber>
   </p1:Telephone>
   <p1:Telephone>
     <p1:Type code="Business">Business</p1:Type>
     <p1:TelephoneNumber>01324 123456</p1:TelephoneNumber>
   </p1:Telephone>
```

The client details are above this in the XML but this is the bit I'm struggling with.

What I would like is to return the data to query analyser as distinct columns, i.e.

```
    Client A | Home | 01234 987654
    Client A | Business | 01324 1234546
    Client B | .... | ....
```

Can someone point me in the right direction for this?

Many Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new XML data type like this assuming the XML looks like in the answer provided by [openshac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283787/openshac) and `YourTable` has one `ClientName` column and one `XMLCol` column.

```
;with xmlnamespaces ('http://org.test' as p1)
select X.ClientName,
       T.N.value('p1:Type[1]/@code', 'varchar(25)') as TypeCode,
       T.N.value('p1:Type[1]', 'varchar(25)') as TypeValue,
       T.N.value('p1:TelephoneNumber[1]', 'varchar(25)') as TelephoneNumber
from YourTable as X
  cross apply X.XMLCol.nodes('/root/p1:Telephone') as T(N)
```

**Edit**

```
;with xmlnamespaces ('f2.co.uk/f2/1.0' as p1) 
select X.ClientReference, 
       T.N.value('p1:Type[1]/@code', 'varchar(25)') as TypeCode, 
       T.N.value('p1:Type[1]', 'varchar(25)') as TypeValue, 
       T.N.value('p1:TelephoneNumber[1]', 'varchar(25)') as TelephoneNumber 
from #tempa as X 
  cross apply X.[Xml].nodes('//p1:CommunicationChannel/p1:Telephone') AS T(N)
```

Comment: thanks Mikael, I think we're getting closer, I have adapted the query slightly to fit into the structure (we have a level higher in the xml called CommunicaionChannel). when I run

Comment: sorry,when i run ;with xmlnamespaces ('http://www.f2.co.uk/f2/1.0' as p1) select X.ClientReference, T.N.value('p1:Type[1]/@code', 'varchar(25)') as TypeCode, T.N.value('p1:Type[1]', 'varchar(25)') as TypeValue, - T.N.value('p1:TelephoneNumber[1]', 'varchar(25)') as TelephoneNumber from #tempa as X cross apply X.[Xml].nodes('//p1:CommunicationChannel/p1:Telephone') AS T(N) I get an error: Operand data type varchar is invalid for minus operator., if I tab out TypeCode and TypeValue the query runs ok, any ideas?

Comment: @user you have a couple of typos in there. One `;` too much and one `-` too much. Updated answer with your version.

Comment: thanks, I found the ;. the - was the problem. all good now, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included your full XML so I can't see where you get the client info from, however try this:

```
    DECLARE @xml nvarchar(max) = '<root xmlns:p1="http://org.test">
   <p1:Telephone>
     <p1:Type code="Home">Home</p1:Type>
     <p1:TelephoneNumber>01234 987654</p1:TelephoneNumber>
   </p1:Telephone>
   <p1:Telephone>
     <p1:Type code="Business">Business</p1:Type>
     <p1:TelephoneNumber>01324 123456</p1:TelephoneNumber>
   </p1:Telephone></root>'

    DECLARE @xml_handle int  
    EXEC sp_XML_preparedocument @xml_handle OUTPUT, @xml, '<root xmlns:p1="http://org.test" />'

    SELECT * FROM 
    OPENXML( @xml_handle, '//p1:Telephone') 
    WITH (
        [Type]              varchar(10) './p1:Type',
        [Code]              varchar(10) './p1:Type/@code',
        [TelephoneNumber]   varchar(10) './p1:TelephoneNumber'
    )

  EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @xml_handle
```

returns:

**Type,Code,TelephoneNumber**

Home,Home,01234 9876

Business,Business,01324 1234

Comment: thanks openshac, that does the trick. I'll investigate those procedures further. Can it be achieved through an array of cross apply's or is that somewhere I shouldnt go?